# Is there any way to have 2 data directories configured while bootstrapping docker daemon?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to understand if there is a way to have 2 different data directories configured while bootstrapping docker daemon. Basically my use case is such that - is there any way I use one data directory for launching some docker containers and saving docker images and once that is full, we use the other data directory.

I am wondering if there is a way to have multiple data directories configured for docker-daemon and when one gets filled, use the other one. Or use certain gigs from this and then fallback on the second one.

Thanks

I did explore the option of running multiple daemons on one host with different data directories [https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#run-multiple-daemons] But the Note on top of it says that this feature is not production ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify 2 data directories for a single docker daemon.